# Как выбрать одну случайную запись из таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (в ней может быть 1 запись, а может 999999999999):

table1:

```
id | name | text
 2 | qqqq | dfgga
 3 | wwww | aaerhea
 5 | wwww | ahndr
 7 | qqqq | ndmttm
 8 | qqqq | fmfmfzf
 9 | qqqq | gnntrm
```

Есть запрос:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name='qqqq' LIMIT 1";
```

Нужно выбрать одну рандомную запись из таблицы.

ORDER BY RAND() работает медленно, 
LIMIT со смещением не подойдёт (тоже работает медленно при большом смещении)

Может быть у кого нибудь есть готовые решения? В моём распоряжении PHP 7.0, MySQL 5.6

Comment: как вариант если id без пропусков - генерить в приложении rand(min_id,max_id) и выбирать конкретную запись
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id >= #rand_id# LIMIT 1

Comment: Судя по запросу, нужна не просто случайная запись, а случайная, которая соответствует условию во WHERE. А это совсем не то же самое, чем просто выбрать случайную запись. Покажите DDL таблицы и cardinality по полю `name` и по каждому индексу, тогда можно будет думать об оптимизации.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно взять максимальное `id` (`MAX()`) и минимальное `id` (`MIN()`), после на PHP сгенерировать между ними случайное число и проверять - есть ли запись с таким `id`. Если записи нет, то инкрементить или декрементить `id` (в зависимости от желания и проверять чтоб не больше `max` и не меньше `min`). Рано или поздно наткнешься на случайную запись. Может сразу, если повезет, может через несколько попыток. Костыль конечно. Но как вариант имеет право на жизнь.

Если поле числовое, то можно использовать не прямое совпадение, а оператор `>` или `<`.